# How do you run applications from the command-line in windows pro?

Tags: java, cmd

I am trying to run

C:\Users\johnkooz>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin\javac.exe

but the cmd response is always

'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Please help! Thanks mates!

Answer (score 1):

Run it like this C:\Users\johnkooz>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin\javac.exe"

Notice quotes.

Comment: It still says that file path is not a valid command, operable program, or batch file.

Comment: do you have a file in that location?

Answer (score 0):

You can also modify the PATH variable so that you can avoid typing the full path to javac.  All you have to do is append C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin; to the PATH variable.  After you do this, just type something like javac -version from any directory to see if things are working.  If it is, you should get the version information.

You can find more info here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html